# MS DVD/USB download tool where is located?

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

After install MS [DVD/USB download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool), I cannot locat it in either Start, neither Program Files. The installer GUI and the MS webpages are not providing any information.

I have Windows 7 x64.

Comment: It's *supposed* to be in the Start menu.

Comment: As I wrote in Start-All programs there is nothing. I tried to repair and reinstall program and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Default install location

Assuming it was installed successfully, it should be located in `%LocalAppData%\Apps\Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool`. This bit of information is also provided in the official download page:

> [...] the location where you installed the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool (e.g. `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool`).
>
> <sub>Source: [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)</sub>

### Manual installation

If for whatever reason you're not able to install the program, follow these steps:

1. Extract the `Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe` file using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).
2. Among the extract files there's one called `Wudt.msi`. Extract it through 7-Zip.
3. Copy the `IoWrapperDll` and `ToolExe` files in whatever folder you like.
4. Rename the copied files to `IoWrapper.dll` and `Windows7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool.exe`, respectively.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you run the installation with another account, the application will only show up for that account.  My normal user account doesn't have local admin rights, so I use a second account with elevated rights to install applications.  I did this and ran into the same  problem.